# How are bond lengths measured experimentally?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, bond, molecular-structure

How is the bond length between any two atoms in a compound measured?

For example, in the case of graphite, the bond between its two layers is 340 pm. This number must have been measured, so what are experiments that can give lengths with that precision?

Comment: Xray crystallography is the most general method, but infra-red and Raman rotational spectroscopy has also been used for smaller molecules. There are some specialised NMR techniques that also measure distance but these are not routinely used as far as I am aware.

Comment: This is something to look up in a basic chemistry textbook, not by googling, especially not for scientific articles. If you haven't got a textbook, try wikipedia?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Has anyone even taken a picture of a molecule to confirm the geometry predicted by theory?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/57784/has-anyone-even-taken-a-picture-of-a-molecule-to-confirm-the-geometry-predicted)

Comment: Transmission electron microscopy is one method of imaging atoms "directly".

Comment: @Mithoron That answer talks about shapes of molecules and not the experimentally measured bond lengths. How's it a duplicate then?

Comment: @GaurangTandon Bond lengths are part of geometry, along with angles.

Comment: @Mithoron "bond length" was only [mentioned once](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/57818/5026) in that linked question, so I was hoping that this question would have more detailing on that part...

Comment: The possible duplicate question is not useful, but the answers are slightly more useful. A good answer here would give much more detail than any of those answers.

Comment: A discussion of all the techniques would be useful as an answer. But it would have distinguish among the alternatives. Gaseous molecules require different techniques to crystals, for example.